# Trouble figuring out how to write an aggregate reporting query

Tags: mysql, datetime, aggregate-functions

| ComputerID | UpdateID | ActionDate | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | AA-AA | 5/1/2023 5PM | 4 |
| 5678 | CC-CC | 5/1/2023 1AM | 4 |
| 1234 | AA-AA | 5/2/2023 7AM | 4 |
| 1234 | CC-CC | 5/1/2023 10AM | 1 |
| 5678 | CC-CC | 5/1/2023 10AM | 4 |
| 1234 | AA-AA | 5/1/2023 1PM | 4 |
| 5678 | EE-EE | 5/1/2023 7PM | 1 |
| 1234 | AA-AA | 5/3/2023 9PM | 4 |
| 1234 | BB-BB | 5/1/2023 11AM | 1 |
| 5678 | CC-CC | 5/1/2023 4PM | 4 |
| 5678 | BB-BB | 5/2/2023 7AM | 1 |
| 1234 | BB-BB | 5/2/2023 11AM | 1 |
| 5678 | AA-AA | 5/4/2023 4PM | 1 |
| 5678 | CC-CC | 5/2/2023 7AM | 4 |
| 5678 | CC-CC | 5/3/2023 11AM | 4 |
| 1234 | AA-AA | 5/4/2023 4PM | 4 |
| 1234 | CC-CC | 5/4/2023 7AM | 4 |

Above is a simple sample of the database I need to write a query for. I am not even sure how (if its even possible) to start this..

**Needed**

- The computers that failed an update **5 times** in the past 7 days, the UpdateID of the update, and how many times it failed.
  -Computers are ComputerID
  -Updates are UpdateID
  -ActionDate (when the update was run) date time stamp
  -Result (4 = Failed)

I am looking for something like this as a result (Pretend today is 5/5/2023):

| ComputerID | UpdateID | FailedCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | AA-AA | 5 |
| 5678 | CC-CC | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a couple of things:

1. Your table name is `updates`, and
2. Your datestamps are stored as `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` data types ...

This query gets what you want (fiddle here https://dbfiddle.uk/XPBXIgR0)

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) Failures,
       ComputerId,
       UpdateId
  FROM updates 
 WHERE Result = 4
   AND ActionDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
 GROUP BY ComputerId, UpdateId
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
 ORDER BY ComputerId, UpdateId
```

Let's break it down bit by bit.

This excludes everything except failures on the most recent seven calendar days.

```sql
   ...
  FROM updates 
 WHERE Result = 4
   AND ActionDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
   ...
```

This summarizes the number of failures by ComputerId and UpdateId.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) Failures,
       ComputerId,
       UpdateId
    ...
 GROUP BY ComputerId, UpdateId
    ...
```

This excludes results involving less than five failures.

```sql
   ...
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
   ...
```

And finally this puts the result set in a predictable order.

```sql
   ...
 ORDER BY ComputerId, UpdateId
```

SQL is made for this kind of thing.